# MySQL PDO not working with PHP 5.3 on Amazon EC2 Apache

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, amazon-ec2

I am running LAMP stack on Amazon EC2 (free tier).

I am trying to connect to an existing MySQL database `myDB` as shown in [W3 example](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp):

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB", $username, $password);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

This outputs `Connected successfully`, but somehow something is not right. I can't do any SQL operations on `$conn` but I don't get any errors either.

I checked that PDO is installed and it is. Here it is:

```
sudo yum install php-pdo
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main/latest
amzn-updates/latest
Package php-pdo-5.3.29-1.7.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

I guess I need to config something somewhere to make PDO work. Can someone help?

Thanks.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/customizing-rds-setup.html